# Sent data through POST method to show in AJAX request

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-class-based-views

Ajax method to post and passing a string to the views.py, the post method in the views.py can receive values from ajax but I cannot get the results value to print back in the ajax success method.

I have tried to return HTTPresponse, redirect, render but nothing seem to work for me.

//Ajax//

```
$("#viewData").click(function(event){

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        tempData : "permView",
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log('{{ result }}')
                    },

                });
                event.preventDefault()
            });
        });
```

//Python//views.py

```
class SpreadSheetView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'spreadsheet.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'type': '86'})

    def post(self, request):
        if request.POST['tempData'] == 'permView':
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'result': "test result"})
```

Comment: Is something printed to the console?

Comment: The console.log prints blank values everytime the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering one of these two problems:

1. You might be getting an error in your view and cannot notice it since you do not cover error case in your ajax request. Just update your ajax request call like this and see if you are getting an error.
2. You are not specifying `dataType` parameterto your request, which causes ajax to incorrectly guess your response type.

To cover these two items, update your request such as:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType : 'html', # or other types, depending on your needs.
      data: {
          tempData : "permView",
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      },
      success: function(data, status) {
          console.log(data)
          console.log(status)
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(status);
          console.log(error);
      }
});
```

Comment: I've updated the code but came across no error, console just prints empty values.

Comment: I've noticed your ajax request does not contain `url` parameter. Are you sure your view is receiving the request successfully?

Comment: the view receives the request sucessfully as it enters the if function with by validating the tempData string.

Comment: I have updated the code but it only prints an empty line and then 'success' in the following line.

Comment: This means your response is entering `success` function with no data. You must make sure the `dataType` you are expecting in your response is correct and you are returning a valid response in your view.

Comment: I've tried to set the data type, and further edit the code but doesn't seem to work. I'm not getting any errors either.